# Custom Adapter retrieve ads from DB but only 7 rows

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter in android, it retrieves a list of 100 rows in a SQLite DB, but when I inflate to a custom ListView, only shows 7 but repeat every X times.

This is the BD Class

```
//Listado de anuncios de determinada catgoria
    public List<Anuncios> getAnuncios(int categoryID) {

        List<Anuncios> anuncios = new ArrayList<>();

        //Cursor cursor = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY).rawQuery(query, null);
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"supercat_id", "header", "price", "name", "image"};
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query(false, "ads", columnas, "supercat_id = " + categoryID, null, null, null, null, "100");

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    Anuncios Ad = new Anuncios();

                    Ad.setAd_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("header")));
                    Ad.setAd_price(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("price")));
                    Ad.setAd_image(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image")));

Log.d("Ad:", Ad.getAd_title()); //To see the ammount of Ads here I see 100

                    anuncios.add(Ad);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ErrorSQLTag", "Error while trying to get posts from database");
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return anuncios;
    }
```

This is the getView in AnunciosAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Anuncios anuncio = this.anuncios.get(position);
        if (convertView != null) {
            return convertView;
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anuncios_row_adapter, null);

        //Imagen
        ImageView foto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        if (anuncio.getAd_image().length > 0) {
            foto.setImageBitmap(Utils.decode2Bitmap(anuncio.getAd_image(), 90, 90));
        } else {
            foto.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_picture);
        }

        //Precio
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice)).setText("$ " + ((float) anuncio.getAd_price()));

        //Header
        TextView titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ad_title);
        titulo.setText(anuncio.getAd_title_reduced());

        return convertView;
    }
```

and this is the Activity:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anuncios);

    int categoryPosition;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        //Id Category
        categoryPosition = extras.getInt("cat_id");

        //Connecting with DB
        Mybd mybd = new Mybd(getBaseContext());
        mybd.checkDataBase();
        mybd.open();

        //Tirando con el adapter
        List<Anuncios> anuncios = mybd.getAnuncios(categoryPosition);



        ListView lvAnuncios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAnuncios);
        adsAdapter = new AnunciosAdapter(getBaseContext(), anuncios);
        lvAnuncios.setAdapter(adsAdapter);

        //Pintando los promoted

    }
}
```

When I inflate in the anuncios_row_adapter I just see 100 ads but really is seven repeated many times

This is an example of Log.d
This is the result when see in debugger the Log.d("Ad:"...

```
bano.elbache D/Ad:: . javier. Samsung S6 y S6 edge. ver precios
05-30 11:06:34.121 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG K7  2016  5 pulg 5 +5  mpx android 5.1 ,8 GB qcore 1.1,1.5 ram  58424161 leydi
05-30 11:06:34.121 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: . javier.  GEVEY R-SIM 10 y tambien R10 PLUS newww. garantia
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: __________Publicamos_su_anuncio_5cuc_mes,3veces_al_dia,vamos_a_su_casa*58262234*
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: ___________________________Publico su anuncio por sms,envia el texto al 58378513
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Se venden moviles de Gama Alta
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Galaxy S7
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CELULAR-BLU life play II- 4.7 pul-Quad-Core-1GB RAM-8GB-8MP-54292738+FORRO
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Galaxy S7
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: SANSUMG S4 MINI  
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: THL T6C 3G Smartphone Color: BLACK  150cuc  5.0 inch Android 5.1 
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: HASTA SU CASA*RECARGA DEL EXTERIOR*Con 25cuc recibe 50 total de saldo,AL MOMENTO,TODOS LOS MESES(54381120)
05-30 11:06:34.122 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: _____*QUIVICAN*RECARGA DEL EXTERIORR*Con 23cuc recibe 50 total de saldo.AL MOMENTO TODOS LOS MESES(54543954)
05-30 11:06:34.123 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG G VISTA|5.7 pulg|8+1.3 mpx|8GB|1.5 GB|Qcore 1.2| 58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.123 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: ________________Club Nacional Por Mensajeria Multimedia
05-30 11:06:34.123 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Cables originales para iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/6PLUS/6S/6SPLUS (Cable Lighting)
05-30 11:06:34.124 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG G Stylo 5.7 Pulg,1.5 GB ram,8+5 mpx,8 GB,5.1 androi 58424161
05-30 11:06:34.124 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG Spree (2016) 4.5 pulg,5 +2 mpx,QCORE 1.1,1 GB RAM, 8GB, 5.1 androi, 58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.124 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Galaxy J7
05-30 11:06:34.124 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: . javier. Samsung Galaxy S7 y S7 EDGE. ver preciossss. elija color 
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Vendo cel Blu Life X8 8Core+1gb RAM+8mp HD+8gb+5''IPS 72610451
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: _____*LIDO*RECARGA DEL EXTERIORR*Con 23cuc recibe 50 total de saldo.AL MOMENTO TODOS LOS MESES(52508622)
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: _____CAPRI*RECARGA DL EXTERIOR.Con 22cuc recibe 50 total d sal2 al momento.Todos los meses(583785I3)
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: AUDIFONOS MANOS LIBRES SAMSUNG   78797454/52491669
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: . javier. Samsung Galaxy S3, S4, S5,   newww wifiii. garantia
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG K8  Feb 2016 |5 pulg|8+5 mpx|Qcore 1.3|1.5 ram|16 GB|androi 6.0-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.125 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG Phoenix 2  may 2016 |5 pulg|8+5 mpx|Qcore 1.3|1.5 ram|16 GB|androi 6.0-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: ****GANGA**** LAPTOP HP ELITEBOOK 8470P SSD 52517912  SENHORES, ESTO ES UN CANHON DE LAPTOP, ES UN CORE I5 PROFESIONAL, CON UNA CARCASA METALICA PARA 
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: PUBLICAMOS SU ANUNCIO POR TODA CUBA Y EL MUNDO. ANUNCIATE 78643659
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: / ATENCION / JAILBREAK para iOS desde 7.0 a 9.3.3 - iPhone 5S, 6, 6+, 6S, 6S+ y mas...
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Galaxy Sol|5''|QCore 1.3GHz|1.5GB|8GB|5+2MP|6.0 Androi-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG K10|5.3pulg|8+5mpx|QC1.3|1.5ram|16Gb|Androi 6.0|58424161-Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LINTERNAS ULTRAVIOLETAS PARA COMPROBAR BILLETES. 53586700
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: . javier. iPhone 6 y 6 PLUS , VER PRECIOS. gangaaaaaaa
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: BUENA HERRAMIENTA DE TRABAJO PARA ELECTRONICOS, MISCROSCOPIO DIGITAL.
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: USB Bluetooth para tu PC o laptop..54972460
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: HTC Desire 626s|5''|QCore 1.1|1.5GB|8GB|8+2MP|5.1 androi-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Micas de cristal templado, ORIGINALES***78797454/52491669
05-30 11:06:34.126 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Protectores para diferentes celulares, lindos y baratos /78797454/52491669
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: TIENDA DE JUGUETES SEXUALES PARA ADULTOS.  SI USTED ESTA BUSCANOD UN REGALO GENIAL PARA UNA PAREJA, O QUIERE AUMENTAR EL CALOR Y EL PICANTE EN SU RELACION, O QUIERE HACRE ALGO NUEVO QUE LO INCITE Y LO
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CABLES HDMI DE PUNTAS DORADAS. 53586700  LSO CABLES ESTAN NUEVOS EN SU NYLON, CON SUS TAPITAS EN LAS PUNTAS, QUE SON DE RECUBRIMIENTO DORADO PARA EVIT
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: .javier. Cambio cualquier telefono, si quiere bajar o subir. solo llamar
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: TIENDA DE JUGUETES SEXUALES PARA ADULTOS.   SI USTED ESTA BUSCANOD UN REGALO GENIAL PARA UNA PAREJA, O QUIERE AUMENTAR EL CALOR Y EL PICANTE EN SU RELACION, O QUIERE HACRE ALGO NUEVO QUE LO INCITE Y L
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: DILDOS DE SILICONA CON COPA DE SUCCION. SUPER BUENOS, SILICONA DE BUENA CALIDAD. 21 CMS. CON TESTICULOS Y PIEL COLOR CARNE. ADAPTABLE.  LLAMA 53586700
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: VENDO CABLE MHL/CONECTA TU DISPOSITIVO MOVIL AL TV/78797454/52491669
05-30 11:06:34.127 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Taller MOVILMAX /Ave. Salvador Allende #1059/ 52494762
05-30 11:06:34.140 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG G3 STYLO|5.5''|13+2 mpx|1GB ram|8GB|QCore 1.3|androi 5.1|- 58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.140 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Lenovo Vibe k5|5''|2GB ram|8core 1.1|13+5 mpx|16 gb|androi 6.0|-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.140 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CELULAR-LG K4- 4.5 pul-Quad-Core-1GB RAM-8GB-5MP-54292738
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CELULAR-LG SPREE- 4.5 pul-QUAD-Core-1GB RAM--5MP-8GB INTERNO 54292738
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: LG G PRO|5.5''FHD|13+2mpx|Qcore 1.7|32GB|2GB ram|-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Samsung Amp Prime|5''|5+2 mpx|Qcore 1.3|1.5 ram|16 GB|androi 6.0|-58424161 Leydi
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CABLE ADAPTADOR DE 4 PINES FUENTE A 8 PINES BOARD. VER 53586700
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: CABLES de DATOS y CARGADOR Android y iPhone -!Y otras ofertas,ENTRA!- 5238-1230
05-30 11:06:34.141 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Forros transparentes iPhones 4, 4S, 5, 5C, 5S, 6 y 6 Plus
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Copie las 100 apps mas usadas en Cuba para iPhone y iPad - $5
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: !!!LO ULTIMO!!! Cargador inalambrico para Samsung Galaxy S3,S4,S5,S6
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Cover (forro) motorola moto e xt1526- 58424161 leydi
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: 2-en-1 -- CABLE de DATOS y CARGADOR para ANDROID -- 5238-1230
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: 2-en-1 --CABLE de DATOS y CARGADOR para iPhone 5,5S,5C,6,6+ -- 5238-1230
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Cable OTG  MicroUSB y USB-C  Conecte memorias USB a su Tablet o Movil
05-30 11:06:34.142 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: Cover (forro) k8,k7,k10, lg l90,core prime,grand prime - 58424161 leydi
05-30 11:06:34.143 31606-31606/com.bachecubano.elbache D/Ad:: 2-en-1 --CABLE de DATOS y CARGADOR para iPhone 3G,3Gs,4,4S, y + -- 5238-1230
```

Comment: Are you sure tehre are 100 unique ads in there and not those 7 being repeatedly loaded into the db?

Comment: This is the result when see in debugger the Log.d("Ad:"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (convertView != null) {
        return convertView;
}
```

If the convertView is not null, it means that an existing cell is being reused, so its subviews must be edited, otherwise it will keep the previous state. So, for instance, a solution could be:

```
View view;
if (convertView != null) {
     view = convertView;
} else {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anuncios_row_adapter, null);
}
```

and then edit and return the variable view instead of convertView

Comment: Thanks, it was this strange piece of code:

if (convertView != null) {
            return convertView;
        }

Comment: Good! :) If you still need an explanation I can edit the code

Comment: Yes, I could need to know why happens that